# Is there something wrong with this energy efficient window?

Tags: windows

There appears to be moisture build up for a single window in a room. Cant tell if its inside or outside the insulation layer.

This is a double panel window (filled with argon gas).

Comment: I guess you can see it. We cannot however extend the internet through your eyes.

Comment: It it's only a single window, then it's likely not condensation on the outside, but on the inside of the panes--which means you have a leaky seal. Need to replace the glass.

Comment: You can't touch the window to tell where the condensation is?

Comment: How to add images when usung a smart phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condensation between the glass on multi-pane windows means the seal is compromised and the inert gas between the panes has escaped. So, yes... something is wrong.